# Skip part of page during crawl

Tags: search, configuration, crawling

Is there any way to mark parts of a page not to be indexed by Microsoft Search Server Express 2010?

For example all pages have footer, and I wan't be able to do something like

```
<div class="no-index">
    footer
</div>
```

And contents of this block should not be indexed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how you do it, but use the class `noindex` instead, like this:

`<div class="noindex"> footer </div>`

Comment: if this div contains links, search server won't follow them in this case?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Just tried it. All content is skipped and if it contains links to other pages they are not get crawled :(

Comment: Then it works as I assumed, and as I expected. Great to know!

Comment: How do you think, div class="noindex follow" will forse search server to follow links inside it?

Comment: But will you have to put noindex on all innertags as well? Can't find any official documentation.

Comment: No, only on the surrounding tag. Anything inside it will not be indexed/followed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Wictor's answer there are some rumors on the internet that you have to make sure you apply the "noindex" to nested DIV's as well. Just putting a "noindex" on the parent node isn't enough to make sure all child nodes are ignored as well. Each child node seems to be re-evaluated for the "noindex" class, according to various sources:
http://sharedknowledgepoint.com/2011/09/12/exclude-page-content-from-search-crawler/
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2010/06/07/control-search-indexing-crawling-within-a-page-with-noindex.aspx

I'm currently working on a FAST implementation (2010) and the above doesn't seem to apply there. I can put "noindex" on a top node and it will ignore everything below. Maybe it's a SharePoint/Search Server issue...