# Prevent search from indexing master page

Tags: search, sharepoint-foundation, master-page

I am using SharePoint Foundation.

When I perform a search of "news", all of my site pages appear in the search results, because there is a "news" link in my master page. I would like it to only search the pages themselves.

Is this possible with SharePoint Foundation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround sections that contain links that you don't want indexed with a div that has class=noindex 
ref: [Skip part of page during crawl](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13187/skip-part-of-page-during-crawl/13188#13188)

Comment: now that i think about it... im confused about this crawling business in general. if i have no links to other pages on my home page, will they ever get indexed? why does sharepoint have to crawl over links rather than simply search through the database?

Comment: The search indexer is a web crawler, if you don't link to a page it doesn't get indexed. It uses this approach, in my estimation, as the end users interact at a web level and thus there is no additional overhead of translating the database relationship etc. in to a web of user accessable pages.

Comment: The database *could* store relations (a.k.a links) between pages but it would be hard to design a database to handle all the different ways pages may be related. You end up having to parse the entire page as if it were HTML so you might as well crawl the rendered pages directly anyway, plus those links are used in the page ranking algorithm.